# how to block model addition with hooks?

Tags: model, hook, loopbackjs

I'm a newbie with loopback and there is something I really don't understand with hooks.

I have a model "question" with these properties : - id - .. - .. - userId

and what I want to do is checking if userId already exists in user table when POST request is called to add a question. (and raise an error, but that is already working)

So I created a before save hook , that is working well (error raised etc) but I can't block the addition of the model, even if I call "next(err)" in my hook.

```
 Question.observe('before save', function isInDb(ctx, next){    
     var PoemUser = app.models.PoemUser;
     var PoemUserId = ctx.instance.id_author;

     PoemUser.findOne({ where: {id: PoemUserId} } ,function(err,exists){
             console.log('exist : ' +exists);
             if (exists == null){
                 var err = new Error();
                 err.name = "id not existing"
                 err.status = 404; // don't know wich code use
                 err.message = "This user is not existing";
                 next(err);
             };
         });

     });
 };
```

I searched on documentation but I think I'm not on the good way with my way of doing it.

It woud be really great if someone could explain me the good way to do what I want to do.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using hook to prevent model addition is quite a good way. I got an impression that you are trying to prevent addition of question when user exists.

Can you please check the following code?

```
PoemUser.findOne({ where: {id: PoemUserId} }, function(err,exists){
        if(err) {
          next(error);
        }
        console.log('exist : ' +exists);
         if (!exists){
             var err = new Error();
             err.status = 404; // don't know which code use
             err.message = "User not found";
             next(err);
         } else {
             next();
         }
     });
 });
```

Double check the property name as you mentioned that Question model contains `userId` field but you are trying to save property `id_author` as in `ctx.instance.id_author`;

Just for information:

- `ctx.instance` will only be available when saving a new question and not when you update a question.
- when you update a question, you'll get the instance in `ctx.data`.

Comment: thanks,
I achieved to make it work,
thank you for information, I didn't know that ! should I have to check if it is an update or addition to work with ctx.instance or ctx.data ? Or is there a way to make it work in both cases?

Comment: You can do like this `var instance = (ctx.instance) ? ctx.instance : ctx.data;` and instance will contain value in both create/update cases.